# How to click a button from a table where all classes have the same name

Tags: java, selenium, button, html-table, click

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="b">
    <td class="t_l">betmatrix</td>
    <td class="t_l">
    <td class="t_r">dsdfsf</td>
    <td class="t_r">NONE</td>
    <td class="t_r">ALL</td>
    <td class="t_r">NONE</td>
    <td class="t_r">ALL</td>
    <td class="t_r">ALL</td>
    <td class="t_r">NONE</td>
    <td class="t_r">ALL</td>
    <td class="t_r">Not required</td>
    <td class="t_r">1.11</td>
    <td class="t_r">All User</td>
    <td class="t_r">0.00</td>
    <td class="t_r">2014-09-05</td>
    <td class="t_r">2014-09-15</td>
    <td class="t_r">2014-09-05</td>
    <td class="t_r">1-admin</td>
    <td class="t_r">
    <td class="t_r">0.00</td>
    <td class="t_r">0.00</td>
    <td class="t_r">
    <td class="t_r">
      <a onclick="showBonusModificationLogs(53599)" href="#">History</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="a">
  <tr class="b">
  <tr class="a">
</tbody>
```

This is the table structure that I have, and there is no way I can search only for specific items in the table.

How can I find an element in a row and then click on the button at the end of the row if it is found?

In this example I would need to search for the word: dsdfsf

It was easier for other tables because the classnames were different. But the same method will not work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @alecxe pointed out, you can use XPath. There are probably hundred different ways of doing this. But to match your requirements I would use: `//tr[td[text()='dsdfsf']]/td/a`. This says: any row that has a column with the text 'dsdfsf', locate a column with an anchor tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can find element [`By.xpath`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-xpath):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//table//tr[td[@class="t_r"] and text() = "dsdfsf"]/td[last()]'));
element.click();
```

The xpath would search in every `tr` inside the `table` for the `td` with class `t_r` and text `dsdfsf`, then would get the last `td` inside the row.